# Are self-closing tags and empty non-closing tags interchangable in XML/Android?

Tags: android, xml

Looking at an example android xml-files I see three nodes where two are self-closing, one is not (but whithout child nodes). Is this of any importance to the compiler or further declations?

```
<set
    xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:shareInterpolator=”false”>
  <rotate
      android:fromDegrees=”0”
      android:toDegrees=”360”
      android:pivotX=”50%”
      android:pivotY=”50%”
      android:duration=”2000” />
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha=”0.0”
      android:toAlpha=”1.0”
      android:duration=”2000”>
  </alpha>
  <scale
      android:pivotX=”50%”
      android:pivotY=”50%”
      android:fromXScale=”.1”
      android:fromYScale=”.1”
      android:toXScale=”1.0”
      android:toYScale=”1.0”
      android:duration=”2000” />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this of any importance to the compiler or further declations?

No. In fact, Android Studio in many cases will suggest that you "collapse the empty tag", to convert an empty XML element into a self-closing variety.

Comment: Android studio needs to look itself deeply in the eyes.. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring a non-self closing tag, you just tell the compiler to look for the body of that tag(or, child nodes in your language). If the body is empty, it will just come out of that tag, and proceed further. While a self-closing tag implies that the tag has zero body(or, no child nodes), and the compiler will not look for any and will just proceed with the next tag(if any).
In terms of performance, I don't think that there is any significant difference between the two. However, to improve the brevity of your code, you should use the self closing tags.